# show/hide title hover fancybox2

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to hide and show title in fancybox2 using hover event, but it doesn't work. Please help.

My code is:

```
    $("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
        $("#fancybox-title").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#fancybox-title").hide();
    })};
```

Comment: If this was solved, you should accept an answer instead of updating the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an extra bracket:

```
$("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
    $("#fancybox-title").show();
}, function() {
    $("#fancybox-title").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use class names; I suggest using 'live' (so you do not need to use callbacks for this)  -

```
$(".fancybox-wrap").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(".fancybox-title").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".fancybox-title").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: In http://api.jquery.com/live/ says : As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). Thanks Janis

Comment: Yes, but not everyone is using v1.7+